# Math.random reoccurring

Tags: javascript, html, int, innerhtml

I am creating a basic modified Crapps game. I am using java script and HTML. So It will not look great, but its purpose is to teach me Java Script.

I am still in the beginning stages and have hit a road block. What is supposed to happen is when I click a button this function happens. My function occurs yet it keep rolling 2 6's and thus the dice show up as 6.

Everything works except that the **6 keeps reoccurring**.

I went through code and could not find common mistakes- making sure the numbers it should generate is covered, that my bases are covered 6 numbers (1-5) all have a job, my names are correct, etc. I know my function is being called because the image of the dice shows up as 6 every time where I want it to go.

```
 function rolldice()
   {
     dice1=Math.floor(Math.random()*6+0);
        if(dice1=0)
            {
             document.getElementById("dice1").innerHTML="<img src='1.jpg' width='100' height='100' />";
            }
        if(dice1=1)
            {
              document.getElementById("dice1").innerHTML="<img src='2.jpg' width='100' height='100' />";

            }
        if(dice1=2)
            {
              document.getElementById("dice1").innerHTML="<img src='3.jpg' width='100' height='100' />";

            }
        if(dice1=3)
            {
              document.getElementById("dice1").innerHTML="<img src='4.jpg' width='100' height='100' />";

            }
        if(dice1=4)
            {
              document.getElementById("dice1").innerHTML="<img src='5.jpg' width='100' height='100' />";

            }
        if(dice1=5)
            {
             document.getElementById("dice1").innerHTML="<img src='6.jpg' width='100' height='100' />";

            }
dice2=Math.floor(Math.random()*6+0);
    if(dice2=0)
            {
             document.getElementById("dice2").innerHTML="<img src='1.jpg' width='100' height='100' />";
            }
        if(dice2=1)
            {
              document.getElementById("dice2").innerHTML="<img src='2.jpg' width='100' height='100' />";

            }
        if(dice2=2)
            {
              document.getElementById("dice2").innerHTML="<img src='3.jpg' width='100' height='100' />";

            }
        if(dice2=3)
            {
              document.getElementById("dice2").innerHTML="<img src='4.jpg' width='100' height='100' />";

            }
        if(dice2=4)
            {
              document.getElementById("dice2").innerHTML="<img src='5.jpg' width='100' height='100' />";

            }
        if(dice2=5)
            {
             document.getElementById("dice2").innerHTML="<img src='6.jpg' width='100' height='100' />";

            }
 }
```

Comment: Use java.util.Random.next() to get int values, and use modulus (`%`) to get your number 0-5.

Comment: And use a `switch` statement instead of the if ladder.

Comment: @HotLicks this is a javascript question

Comment: @ben336 - Ah, so 'tis.  Never mind.

Comment: (If it were Java the bug that Logan pointed out would have been impossible.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `=` instead of `==`. That means that it will run each of the statements from 1-5.

```
if (dice1 = 5){
```

is the same as

```
dice1 = 5;
if (dice1){
```

Which will always be true.

You should also have `var` before each of your variables when you are assigning the random value, FYI.

I would consider shortening all of this code to something like this:

```
function rolldice(){
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    document.getElementById('dice' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = 
      "<img src='" + (roll + 1) + ".jpg' width='100' height='100' />"
  }
}
```

Comment: That was it! Knew I overlooked something. Thanks for the quick response!